# Diccionario inverso en línea / Online reverse dictionary

Tags: recursos

Me interesa saber si existe un diccionario de español en línea, en donde se puedan buscar las palabras por las últimas y no por las primeras letras.

Por ejemplo:

> Si uno desea buscar *caramba*, uno teclea "*ab...*" y debe aparecer la lista de palabras que comienzan con *ab*: *ábaco, abanico, etc.* como sugerencias, de tal manera que uno obtenga todas las palabras (estándar) con un número deseado de letras finales comunes.

¿Alguna referencia?

---

Is there an online reverse Spanish dictionary: i.e. the input are the last letters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Puedes usar [GoodRAE](http://recursosdidacticos.es/goodrae/).

Por ejemplo, para buscar palabras terminadas en 'osal', busca por [*osal](http://recursosdidacticos.es/goodrae/index.php?buscar=%2aosal&_pagi_pg=1) y obtendrás *colosal*, *corrosal*, *fosal*, *rosal* y *sosal*.

---

You can use [GoodRAE](http://recursosdidacticos.es/goodrae/).

For example, to search for words ending with 'osal', do a search for [*osal](http://recursosdidacticos.es/goodrae/index.php?buscar=%2aosal&_pagi_pg=1) and you'll get *colosal*, *corrosal*, *fosal*, *rosal* and *sosal*.

Answer (score 2):

I do not know of any on-line reverse spanish language dictionary.  However, I did publish "A Reverse Dictionary of the Spanish Language" in 1973.  It is available at most research libraries.  You can find all the answers to inquiries you might have in it. I did the work in 1966 because of a spanish linguistics course wherein I needed to know all the words that ended in a specific suffix and couldn't find an source for the information, so I built it.

I do have the data in digital format but have never made it available.
If you cannot locate a copy please let me know where you are and I will see if I can find one near you.

Answer (score 0):

En el sitio hermano de alemán, pregunté algo [similar](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/7335/german-dictionary-with-reverse-words). En la respuesta se sugiere usar [dict.leo](http://dict.leo.org/esde). Quizá para muchos, sería también útil aplicar misma búsqueda que sugiere @dusan, en [dict.cc](http://enes.dict.cc/?s=*endo) pues la traducción al inglés (u otro idioma) aparece al dar click en la palabra.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the RAE's DLE has this function e.g. [**search:** *ba](https://dle.rae.es/ba?m=32):

[image]